# Time complexity of 2 for loops with a O(n) operation

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have 2 for loops with an operation which would take o(n) inside 1 of the nested for loops.

```
for (i=0;i<someLength;i++){
  for(j=i+1;j<someLength;j++){
      //some operation requiring O(n)
     }
}
```

What will be the overall complexity?

Comment: You should perhaps be more concerned about the complexity/time with respect to `someLength` than with respect to `n`.

Comment: assuming someLength is very big.

Comment: @srock, I edited my answer with an explanation. If you have any additional questions, I'll be glad to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mohamed above in mathematical terms, the complexity for the code in question is O(n^3).

Quick explanation(worst case i.e. looping through the entire loop):

Outer FOR loop complexity = O(n)

Inner FOR loop complexity = O(n)

Total complexity so far = O(n^2)

Now, in my question I had mentioned there was an operation inside the inner FOR loop which had a complexity of O(n) --> which is almost the same as 1 more FOR loop inside the Inner FOR loop, that makes the total complexity O(n^3).

Answer (score 1):

You can formally represent your loops using Sigma notation, then expand it:

[image]

Comment: O(n^3) is what I would imagine the answer to this is as well, but could you explain how you went from the single Sigma to the fractions?

Comment: Go to [http://pastebin.com/83Rar9eY](http://pastebin.com/83Rar9eY), copy the LaTeX code, then go to [http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), and paste it there. You'll see the demonstration. Otherwise, you can take advantage of WolframAlpha (like [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum[+%28n+-+i+-+1%29+]+with+i+from+0+to+n+-+1)).

Comment: Thank you for the demonstration. I feel dumb now, XD. Your `(\frac{n^2 - n}{2})` took me a while to understand. I'm used to seeing `(\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2})` instead and just didn't put it together. Anyways, +1 to you and -1 to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Big-Oh of two nested `for` loops is O(n^2), assuming that "someLength" is very large.

### Explanation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     cout << "i: " << i << " ";
}
```

The above code executes in `.02` seconds according to the compiler on my system (using `<ctime>` library).

In this case `n` is equal to `100`. So `100/.02` = `5000`.

---

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < 100; j++)
    {
        cout << "i: " << i << " " << endl << "j: " << j << " ";
    }
}
```

The above equates to `~1.9` seconds. Now using the fact that the Big-Oh of two nested `for` loops is O(n^2).

Since `n` is equal to `100`, we have `100^2` or `10000`. So using the result of `5000` from the above calculation, we get `10000/5000` = `2` seconds.

`1.9` seconds is close enough to `2` seconds, therefore the run-time of your block of code is indeed O(n^2).

Comment: what about the fact that in the nested for loop I had in my code above had an operation which took O(n).

Comment: Adding two `n` digit numbers is a O(n) operation. So inserting an addition operator inside the nested `for` loop makes no difference on the run-time. It was still O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm sorry, but how is adding 2 integer O(n) operation?
Edit: 
Say the operation inside the inner for loop is searching a linkedlist (whose complexity is o(n)).

Comment: @srock [Wikipedia has all the mathematical operations' time complixity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations). I ran a linear search through an array inside nested `for` loops and it was indeed O(n^2). [You can play around with this code to get an idea of how Big-Oh.](http://pastebin.com/9qQSaBzS)

Comment: I have commented the explanation below. The complexity is O(n^3). Thanks